# New Message Notification in badges

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-ui

I do have a UI where Customer Dashboard consisting of a Menu is there Which includes multiple Submenus out of which i do have a Submenu called as Message.Now i want to show the Notification for the new message in Badges.If new message comes it should show me the Badge as "New Message".if I read that message it must vanish.
My code is as follows:
CSS:

```
.notification-bubble {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background: #f56c7e url(../images/notification-bg-clear.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-image: none\9;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: -10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 18px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .17), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .17), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .17), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.notification-bubble.show {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("MyMessage","ForumPost")"><span class="notification-bubble">New Message</span>My Message</a></li>
```

Comment: You've given us the UI code, where is the code which deals with retrieving messages, or checking for new messages? If thats what you want someone to write for you, you need to re-read the FAQ.

Comment: You are going to need Ajax to poll for any unread messages and if there are then update the necessary html element with the appropriate CSS style to show that there is a new/unread message

Comment: yess...but what could me the code?